# Different behavior of DAX measures depending on nesting

Tags: dax

I wanted to calculate the median of the total sales for each category.

If I create the following two measures, it works perfectly:

```
SoS := SUM(Table1[Sales])
Median Category Sales := 
      MEDIANX(
              CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[Category]), ALL(Table1)), 
              [SoS]
              )
```

However, If I don't nest the measures the median is not calculated and it returns just the sum.

```
   Median without measure := 
      MEDIANX(
              CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[Category]), ALL(Table1)), 
              SUM(Table1[Sales])
              )
```

See results below:

[image: DAX Measures Nesting]

Why this happens? I thought the two approaches were exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the first approach is equivalent to the following:

```
Median Category Sales := 
MEDIANX(
    CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Table1[Category]), ALL(Table1)), 
    CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Sales]))
    )
```

The SoS measure implicitly wraps its formula in a CALCULATE which causes a context transition for each Category provided through VALUES, thereby correctly calculating the sume of sales and therefore the median.

Comment: Of course!!! That's why I always wrap the aggregation functions around calculate when using `TOPN`.

Thanks!